# Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to figure ut the rules for firestore, however I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
E/flutter (14485): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.update (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:59:7)
E/flutter (14485): <asynchronous suspension>
```

currently, my rules are set to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**}{
 allow read: if true;
allow create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
}
match /users/{userId}/images/{imageId} {
allow create, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
 }
}
```

am new to this. help appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Could you also attach the code containing the document path and the command you tried to access ?

Comment: are you also using FlutterFire? if so, please add the tag.